# Trouble with Uwsgi settings

Tags: nginx, django, uwsgi

I have a uwsgi ini that looks like this:

```
[uwsgi]

socket = :8001
processes = 4
master = true
wsgi-file = /project/dev/myproject/conf/deployment/wsgi/dev/myproject-site.wsgi
harakiri = 30
daemonize = /logs/log/myproject/myproject-uwsgi.log
uid = www-data
gid = www-data
plugins-dir = /usr/lib/uwsgi/plugins
plugins = python34
```

I seem to be having trouble loading the python34 plugin:

```
found fd 3 mapped to socket 0 (:8001)
running /usr/local/bin/uwsgi
*** has_emperor mode detected (fd: 5) ***
[uWSGI] getting INI configuration from /project/dev/myproject/conf/deployment/wsgi/dev/myproject.ini
open("./python34_plugin.so"): No such file or directory [core/utils.c line 3675]
!!! UNABLE to load uWSGI plugin: ./python34_plugin.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory !!!
*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.8 (64bit) on [Tue Nov 18 09:08:10 2014] ***
compiled with version: 4.8.2 on 18 November 2014 08:18:15
```

However, the file does seem to be located where i'm telling it to look:

```
me@BF-WEB02:/usr/lib/uwsgi/plugins$ ls -l /usr/lib/uwsgi/plugins/python34_plugin.so 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 165216 Mar 23  2014 /usr/lib/uwsgi/plugins/python34_plugin.so
```

I installed uwsgi initially with pip. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you run uwsgi with ``sudo``? The file is only available for root, but it should give a Permission Denied in that case. The other option is that it is not trying to load it from ``/usr/lib/uwsgi/plugins`` because it says: ``./python34_plugin.so``. It is trying to load it from whatever is the current workdir.

Answer (score 2):

This is identical to the an [issue](https://github.com/unbit/uwsgi/issues/1992) raised with uwsgi and epxlained as follows:

> you have uwsgi in /usr/local and plugins in /usr, it doesn't look
> right, looks like you two uwsgi installations and mixing them

The solution is to decide which binaries to use, and stick with it. The problem goes away as soon as not attempting to load `/usr/`-installed plugins from a `/usr/local/`-installed uwsgi build.